# htaccess Limit overide?

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to override an htaccess file in a subdirectory? Been Googling for the past couple hours and turned up nothing useful.

I want to block some IP's & unwanted bots, but my 403 page is in a subdirectory, so I have to override the `Deny`'s in it but `Allow from all` doesn't seem to undo the `Deny`'s. Here's the code I've been trying:

/public_html/.htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 111.13.8.*
</LIMIT>

<Files "/errors/">
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

It returns a 500 error. Since the bot can't access the `errors` subdirectory's htacess file, this code would have to go here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
<Files "/errors/*">
```

instead of

```
<Files "/errors/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shrink your `.htaccess` to just

```
<Limit GET POST>
Deny from 111.13.8.*
</LIMIT>
```

And you can have a `.htaccess` in each subdir, so you could do in subdir `errors`:

```
<Limit GET>
Allow from *
</LIMIT>
```

See http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess.html for usage of the `Files` directive.

All with the assumption that you are allowed to override directives in your public_html directories at all.